# .Net Core 6 can't handle german umlauts

Tags: c#, .net-core, character-encoding, str-replace

I have a x86 **com api** which imports into an app some files from a net drive. When I access the com api with .net 4.8 everything works fine but i get troubles when the path has german umlauts and I run the .net core 6.

Any chance I can do some encoding to tell the com api what the path is or to tell .net to handle umlauts differently?

**EDIT:**

Can I replace the net share path from A2lSourceFullName and HexSourceFullName so that the com api understands where the files are located.

```
        Cebra.Inca.Asap2Project file = incaFolder.ReadASAP2FileAndHexFile(A2lSourceFullName, HexSourceFullName);
```

EDIT2:
The com api is from the company ETAS the program is called INCA 7.2. Sadly without the tool it probably not possible to reproduce the error for others.

EDIT3:
I am not really familiar with "Process Monitor" but I don't see a difference in when the api call succeeds and when it does not.

[image]

Comment: What kind of troubles exactly?  What is your code doing with path strings?  You tagged [str-replace], but the question seems to be lacking a [mcve].  Do you suspect that it's specific to x86 and wouldn't happen on ARM or something?  Likely the [x86] tag isn't really relevant; you can add it back in if it turns out the problem is specific to 32-bit x86 but not other .net architectures.  You already mentioned x86 in the question body where it belongs; x86 (assembly language / performance) experts aren't going to have any special insight into answering this question.

Comment: I tagged str-replace because I hoped there is a way I can encode the string with umlauts so that the com api understands again what I am giving for inputs.
Because the com dll works with .net4.8 and not .net core 6. I thought maybe x86 is not so well supported anymore in .net core 6.

Comment: Ok, that explains the tagging, but isn't a [mcve] or a description of exactly what "troubles" you run into.  What do you see with a debugger in the bytes of your strings?  What exactly are some of the problems that happen?

Comment: I could load up the dll but without the hole application the dll does not work at all. So without that i don't know how to give an reproducible example. And the app is not possible to download without a license.

Comment: Sadly I don't get any error. The string with the umlauts looks fine when i pass it to the ReadASAP2FileAndHexFile method. But then I don't even get an error the result is just empty.

Comment: If you use a system-call tracing tool, do you see a failed OpenFile system call / winapi call?  If it's a commercial product, can't you ask their support about the problem you're having using it with .net 6?